# What does it mean when someone says an reference cannot be changed in C++

Tags: c++

Recently, I am reading some books about C++ such as "C++ primer" and "Effective C++".Almost every books say that a reference cannot be changed. I am confused with this statement.
Because, I can write down code like this.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int& c = a;
// then I can change the reference c without compile errors.
c = b;
```

So, I cannot understand what dost it mean a reference cannot be changed.

Comment: Ok, I've got the idea about the reference, thank you all guys very much.

Comment: You  might want to consider accepting the answer which you found most useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When people say that a reference cannot be changed, they mean that you cannot change which object the reference is referencing... For example, with pointers, you can do this:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int *c = &a; // c points to a
c = &b;      // c now points to b instead
*c = 3;      // b now equals 3
```

There's no equivalent code for references. Once you initialize the reference:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int &c = a;
```

You can't change the reference so that the statement `c = 3;` now changes `b` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Once a reference is assigned to a target any further use of that reference refers to the target, not the reference itself.

For example, `int& c = a;` creates a reference called `c` whose target is `a`. But if you then try to change it, as in `c = b;` you are changing the value of `a`, not changing the target of `c`.

Comment: I would really stay away from using "points at" when talking about references.

Comment: Point taken although when answering questions it's good to consider the technical level of the person asking them - I tend to favour plain language when it's fairly obvious the OP is out of their depth.

Answer (score 2):

> Pointers and reference are two mechanisms for referring to an object
>   frome different places in a program without copying.

The consistence of reference can be understood by comparing with pointers.

```
char a{'a'};
char b{'b'};
char *p = &a;
p = &b;
```

[image]
The pointer `p` is pointer to different object changing from `a` to `b`.
In the case of reference:

```
char &r = a;
r = b;
```

[image]
The reference in expression is always dereferenced automatically. So it with change the value of the object it referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = b;
```

In the above statement you are assigning the value of `b` to the value of `a` as  `c` is    still referring to the the variable `a`